# How to Trigger a ClassCastException? I'm trying to unit test a class and there is this try/catch segment which i'm not able to check

Tags: java, junit5

```java
public int compare(Cat cat1, Cat cat2) {

        try {
            Cat obj1 = cat1;
            Cat obj2 = cat2;
            return obj1.getCode().compareTo(obj2.getCode());
            //compareTo returns 0/1, getCode returns a string color of cat.
        } 
        catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new CatRuntimeException("Comparison failed.");
        }
}
 //want to test the catch part.
```

Comment: What operation is causing the class cast exception? i dont see you casting any objects? what does Cat::getCode do?

Comment: Why do you have that catch block at all? Why would this ever throw `ClassCastException`? (I guess your `getCode()` method could, but that sounds unlikely...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to trigger it

```
Cat c1 = mock(Cat.class);
Cat c2 = mock(Cat.class);
when(c1.getCode()).thenThrow(new ClassCastException());
yourObject.compare(c1, c2);
```

Answer (score -1):

You’d want to call the fuction in a way that causes the exception and then check if it gets thrown. Here‘s a link that might help: https://www.baeldung.com/junit-assert-exception